# Creating a php associative array that can be json encoded

Tags: php, arrays, json

Ok so I have a could similar to this.

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "user", "password", "DB");
if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
    echo "failed to connect:" . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$grab = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM DB");
$cars = while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($grab)){
     "id" => $row["Id"], "name" => $row["Name"], "color" => $row["Color"];
}
json.encode($cars);
```

So I know that the while loop is a bit strange, but I need to know how I adjust the code so I can json encode the resulting variable, so I get an array of associative arrays.

I know this code wont work but how do I get it to work, I'm guessing its going to take a little more work, but am very new to coding and php.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: json_encode not json.encode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$cars = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($grab)){
     $cars[] = array("id" => $row["Id"], "name" => $row["Name"], "color" => $row["Color"]);
}
json_encode($cars);
```

this is correct syntax and method

Comment: putting this just outputs "array" string.

Answer (score 0):

Close?

```
$the_array = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($grab)) {
    $temp = array();
    $temp['id'] = $row['Id'];
    $temp['name'] = $row['Name'];
    $temp['color'] = $row['Color'];
    $the_array[] = $temp;
}
json_encode($the_array);
```

Comment: this doesn't work either, just returns string "array".

Answer (score 0):

1. mysql methods are depreciated in PHP, try to use `PDO` extension.
2. Use the following

> ```
> $grab = mysql_query($con, "SELECT * FROM DB");
> $cars = array(); $i = 0;
> while($row = mysql_fetch_array($grab))
>      $cars[$i++] = array("id" => $row["Id"], "name" => $row["Name"], "color" => $row["Color"]);
> header('Content-Type: application/json');
> json.encode($cars);
> ```

Comment: I dont have a compiler right now, can you get the idea and take care of the sytax to try? Also you need to set the headers. I updated the answer, please check again.